# Destroying and Re-initializing Turn.js

Tags: turnjs

I have a web page where I'm using `turn.js` and wish to destroy and re-initialize the plug-in if a user resizes the page to below a certain threshold. I'm testing this as follows:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if (Modernizr.mq('(min-width: 764px)')) {
        $("#flipbook").turn("destroy");
    }
});
```

However I'm not sure how to re-initialize `turn.js` subsequently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close: Just one more thing needed was to add `$( window ).unbind( 'keydown' );` and then re-initialize by adding `.turn()` again;

`$( '#book' ).turn( 'addpage', element, pageNo );` is the proper way of doing it but I don't want to return just a block of HTML. I prefer reloading the entire `div`. So what worked for me was:

```
// data is html ajax response
// destroy any previous bindings'
if ( $( '#book' ).turn( 'is' ) ) {
        $( '#book' ).turn( 'destroy' );
        $( window ).unbind( 'keydown' );
}

$( '#book' ).html( data );

// load the book
$( '#book' ).turn({
    display: 'double'
    , acceleration: true
    , gradients: !$.isTouch
    , elevation:50
});
```